# Reading secret using AWS SDK for JavaScript from ECS Fargate Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm working on implementing the AWS SDK for JavaScript within my containerized application hosted on ECS Fargate. I have a secret stored in Secrets Manager that I trying to read from within the codebase. So far I have:

1. Updated the IAM role associated with the Fargate task to read the secret value from Secrets Manager
2. Updated the JavaScript code to include the AWS SDK and read the value into a variable

After I deploy the changes to Fargate, I am getting an error dealing with an unexpected token dealing with ClientRequestToken.

Initially I believed this is happening because I do not have a shared credentials file or anything setup within the code base to authenticate to AWS. I am now believing I shouldn't need that integration because there is an IAM role that provides access to read the secret value.

Below is the code file where I am using the AWS SDK for JavaScript and also the Cloudwatch logs that specifies the error. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
import getSearchQueryString from './query-string-builder';
import {
  SecretsManagerClient,
  GetSecretValueCommand,
  CancelRotateSecretCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager";

var BASE_PORT = "xxxx"

(async function () {
    const secret_name = "secret";
    const client = new SecretsManagerClient({});

    let response;
        
    try {
      response = await client.send(
        new GetSecretValueCommand({
          SecretId: secret_name,
          VersionStage: "AWSCURRENT", // VersionStage defaults to AWSCURRENT if unspecified
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      // For a list of exceptions thrown, see
      // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
      throw error;
    }

    const secret = response.SecretString;
})();

function fetch(endpoint) {

  //noinspection JSUnusedLocalSymbols
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const request = require('node-fetch');

    console.log("Accessing " + secret + ":" + BASE_PORT + endpoint);
    return request(`${secret}:${BASE_PORT}${endpoint}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
        return resolve(json)})
      .catch(err => {
        console.error("error in fetch", err)
        var result = {
          errors: true,
          error: err
        }
        resolve(result)
    });
  });
}

function baseFetch(searchQuery, pageNum) {
  const pageLength = 10;

  var pageIdx = 1;
  if (pageNum && pageNum != 0)
    pageIdx = pageNum;

  var offset = (pageIdx - 1) * pageLength + 1;

  var endpoint = "/v1/search?q=" + searchQuery + "&options=basic&transform=searchres&start=" + offset;

  return fetch(endpoint);
}

export function fetchFacilityById(id, utilStartYear) {
  var endpoint = `/v1/documents?uri=/facility/${utilStartYear}/${id}.xml&transform=guide`;
  return fetch(endpoint);
}

export function fetchSystemById(searchId) {
  var endpoint = `/v1/documents?uri=/system/${searchId}.xml&transform=guide`;
  return fetch(endpoint);
}

export function searchSuggestions(searchTerm, searchType) {
  var encSearchTerm = encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);
  var endpoint = `/v1/suggest?partial-q="${encSearchTerm}&format=json&options=${searchType}`;

  return fetch(endpoint);
}

export function advancedSearch(searchOpts) {

  var searchTerm = encodeURIComponent(getSearchQueryString(searchOpts));

  return baseFetch(searchTerm, searchOpts.pageNum);
}
```

Cloudwatch Error

```
message
> guide-graphql@1.0.8 dockerstart /app
> node dist/app.js
/app/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_1.js:1348
"        ClientRequestToken: input.ClientRequestToken ?? (0, uuid_1.v4)(),"
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/aha/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager/dist-cjs/commands/CancelRotateSecretCommand.js:8:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! guide-graphql@1.0.8 dockerstart: `node dist/app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the guide-graphql@1.0.8 dockerstart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-10T15_22_46_112Z-debug.log
```

Comment: That error means something is simply wrong with your code / the way you bundle your code / the runtime you selected. It literally tells you that node does not understand the code, namely the `nullish coalescing operator` `??`. What node version are you using and what version of the aws-sdk? This is unrelated to ECS, to IAM, to any permissions and generally unrelated to AWS as a way to run your code and more about the AWS dependency you have in your code.

Comment: I see. The version of Node running in the container is 10.24.1. The version of the SDK is version 3

Comment: What happens when you run the same docker image locally? This looks like something you should be able to reproduce and debug locally before involving any AWS deployments.

Comment: https://node.green/ => `??` is only supported from node 14.5 upwards. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html states *"The code examples for V3 in this guide are written in ECMAScript 6 (ES6). ES6 brings new syntax and new features to make your code more modern and readable, and do more. ES6 requires you use Node.js version 13.x or higher."*. Obviously not a perfect match but it is certain that 10.24.1 is too old / not supported.